# Implement those circles that are shown under the images to show the position of the image

Tags: android, image

I don't know the what they called, to show my product image i need to put the bar which mostly place on the bottom of the image, its usually shown like circle and its shown the number of images and shows which image user is looking at, for example in the case that we have four images, there are four little circle under the image which one of them is filled white and three others are unfilled,
what I need is the name of it and the way I'm able to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are referring to the ViewPager

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

you may also have a look at https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/